# How to integrate Pinterest using OpenURL?

Tags: ios, social-networking, pinterest

I have tried calling pinterest app using ios OpenURL scheme but **canOpenURL** method always return false. I need help to get it work as i'havent find any solution by google. I dont want to use UIWebView to get it working. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a [link](http://www.varshylmobile.com/pinterest-framework-for-ios) that has a way to pin a picture to pinterest.  It is a framework that works pretty well. But you can not repin something from someone's pin board.  If you search SO you should find some other answers as well.  People trying to overcome the fact there is no API currently.  Hope this gives you a jump start.

Comment: I had tried this framework but its not working properly.Dont know what i'm doing wrong.Thanks for reply :)